# FastAPI Gunicorn fails to work via Supervisor

Tags: fastapi, supervisord

If I run this command from my fastAPI folder, it works perfectly fine. The API is running. I can connect to the database; everything is just fine.

```
/home/fauser/fastapifolder/.virtual/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py main:app
```

In supervisor config file I have:

```
[program:fastapi]
directory=/home/fauser/fastapifolder/fastapi
command=/home/fauser/fastapifolder/.virtual/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py main:app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/fauser/fastapifolder/fastapi/logs/gunicorn-error.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

The Supervisor gives me Starting status. And when I check `gunicorn-error.log`, I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'None'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
[2023-04-05 17:46:48 +0000] [8379] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8379)
[2023-04-05 17:46:48 +0000] [8377] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8379 was terminated due to signal 15
[2023-04-05 17:46:48 +0000] [8377] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-04-05 17:46:48 +0000] [8377] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I don't understand what is going on. If something were wrong with the database and code, I could not run the service with the first command. It works perfectly.

I am not even sure where the problem is. On the side of the supervisor or some rights, but I don't understand. I would appreciate any resolution.

Comment: When you're running under gunicorn your environment settings are not getting picked up - so the username/password/etc. for the database are the default values. I'm guessing you don't have a user named `None`. How are you configuring the database credentials?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, this is correct. What I did is I pasted user's environment settings into root .profile for testing. I ran supervisor and still the same problem. I really don't understand. But it has to be something with user rights.

Comment: `.profile` is only read by interactive shells. It does not get read by a daemon such as `supervisord`. Either use `environment` [with kv-pairs in your supervisord-file](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment), or use a .env file if your settings library support them (which I why I asked how you were configuring your database credentials).